# SELinux denied clamscan to delete uploaded file on nginx server

Tags: centos, nginx, selinux, clamav

On my nginx server, the uploaded files context are set as:

```
-rw-rw-r--. nginx nginx system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 eicar.sh.pdf
```

Right after upload, clamscan runs to verify the file using *php exec()* as an nginx user.

```
/usr/bin/clamscan --quiet --remove /opt/myserver/files/eicar.sh.pdf
```

And this throws a SeLinux write access denial, when clamscan tries to delete that file *(its a EICAR test file)*.

The audit logs suggests to create a policy which i am not in favor of:

```
# ausearch -c 'clamscan' --raw | audit2allow -M my-clamscan
# semodule -i my-clamscan.pp
```

These are already set:

```
sudo setsebool -P antivirus_can_scan_system 1
sudo setsebool -P antivirus_use_jit 1
```

**Q:** Is there is a way to fix this via file context, but don't want to loose the current context httpd_sys_rw_content_t for the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting **antivirus_t** as **permissive** worked. This makes SeLinux to not to enforce its policies for all antivirus.

```
sudo semanage permissive -a antivirus_t
```